# How can I save multiple Listbox value

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, listbox

after selecting values from another listbox I save multiple listbox value into a single column of a table using linq to entity

```
protected void link1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lb1.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        lb2.Items.Add(new ListItem(lb1.SelectedItem.Text, lb1.SelectedItem.Value));
        lb1.Items.RemoveAt(lb1.SelectedIndex);
    }
}
protected void link2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lb2.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        lb1.Items.Add(new ListItem(lb2.SelectedItem.Text, lb2.SelectedItem.Value));
        lb2.Items.RemoveAt(lb2.SelectedIndex);
    }
}
protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Skill = lb2.SelectedItem.Text;

    employee e1 = new employee();
    e1.emp_skill = Skill;
    je.employee.AddObject(e1);
    je.SaveChanges();

    mv.ActiveViewIndex = 4;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this ? I iterate throught all elements of the listbox Id = "lb2"

```
protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        for(var i=0;i<lb2.Items.Count;i++)
        {
            var e1 = new employee() { emp_skill = lb2.Items[i].Text };
            je.employee.AddObject(e1);
        }
        je.SaveChanges();
}
```

if you only want the selected items in the listbox Id= "lb2" :

```
protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        ListItem item = null;
        for(var i=0;i<lb2.Items.Count;i++)
        {
            item = lb2.Items[i];
            if (item.Selected)
            {
                var e1 = new employee() { emp_skill = item.Text };
                je.employee.AddObject(e1);
            }
        }
        je.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Yes sorry - i have fixed my answer

Comment: Now its saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: "Line 202:        string Skill = lb2.SelectedItem.Text;" Showing error on this line

Comment: So what should i use.? Sorry i am new in .net

Comment: @Sayantan Das : copy one of the 2 methods i wrote for you and paste it to replace your existing one

Comment: Store-generated keys are only supported for identity columns. Key column 'emp_email' has type 'SqlServer.varchar', which is not a valid type for an identity column

Comment: @Sayantan Das : this is something else - It seems you have an incorrect mapping with you entity class